# Is there a master list of journals?

Tags: journals, databases, repository

I'm looking for a repository of journal data.
More specifically, a listing of every known journal name and various attributes such as ISSN, rankings, peer review, etc. I know Cabell's offers this information, but expressly forbids mass-downloading.
Is there a better source for Journal data?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no. There is no comprehensive list of academic journals, and I doubt there ever will be. The major reason for it is there is no real need as publishing culture varies a lot by field and geography. Plus, in the recent explosion of scholarly publishing, there is probably a new journal every week or so.

However there are curated databases of journals. For example, Thomson Reuters has a service called [Web of Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_Science) that provides libraries with a large list of journals (about 12'000 according to Wikipedia) and publication metrics, such as citation count, rank by discipline and impact factor. I used this service a few times to check the ranking of journals before submitting papers.

Libraries often let affiliates download the full report as a spreadsheet that you can manipulate the way you want. Contact your local library, most institutions subscribe to this database.

Also, [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_databases_and_search_engines) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

At the university where I did my PhD, we used the [Norwegian Scientific Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Scientific_Index) to establish what journals were considered "valid" for an internal system of redistributing money based on scientific output.  From Wikipedia:

> The index divides journals and publishers into "level 1" and "level 2", where "level 2" is reserved for the internationally[1] most prestigious journals and publishers within the discipline

(...)

> Currently, 2,144 academic journals and series are designated as Level 2, i.e. journals and series considered to be the most highly regarded

This is not a *complete* list, but a list that aims to contain the "good" journals within each discipline.

I don't know about mass downloading — perhaps the folks at the [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) have a better take on that.

Comment: There are many such national lists for funding and evaluation purposes. They tend to be heavily controversial.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Journal Citation Reports](http://thomsonreuters.com/en/products-services/scholarly-scientific-research/research-management-and-evaluation/journal-citation-reports.html) list provided by Thompson Reuters. To access it you will need to ask your library.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a list of "good" journals, [DOAJ](https://doaj.org/) (Directory of Open Access Journals) is probably what you need. It contains about 12 thousand journals passing certain checks, of which over 1000 with further quality controls (DOAJ seal).

[Wikidata](https://wikidata.org) is [open data](https://opendefinition.org/) and run by a non-profit, as well. It's participatory and general purpose and it has a lot of data on journals, partly thanks to a specific initiative called [WikiCite](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/WikiCite).

You can rather easily query and download a [list of all academic journals](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28MIN%28%3FpublisherLabel%29%20AS%20%3FpublisherLabel%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28MIN%28%3Fissn%29%20AS%20%3Fissn%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28MIN%28%3FlicenseLabel%29%20AS%20%3FlicenseLabel%29%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ737498%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP236%20%3Fissn%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP123%20%3Fpublisher%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP275%20%3Flicense%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel) (and subclasses thereof). As of now I see about 50 thousands results, nearly all of them having ISSN and many also license and publisher information. See the [SPARQL query service documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service) on how to tweak the query.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that comes to a master list of journals is the following:

This [CSV-file on GitHub](https://github.com/andreaspacher/academic-publishers/blob/main/Output/alljournals-2021-02-05.csv) containing ca. 25.000 journals belonging to 137 major* publishers. You can also browse through the same list on [this website](https://ooir.org/journals/).

The catalogue stems from a project that scraped data based on (1) DOAJ, (2) Publons, (3) Scopus and (4) Sherpa Romeo.

For details, see the pre-print [here](https://doi.org/10.31235/osf.io/56b28).

---

* I.e., publishers that supposedly had at least 30 journals in their portfolio based on the journal counts in one of the four data samples (DOAJ, Publons, Scopus or Sherpa Romeo).

Answer (score -1):

You might find the Australian ERA list useful. It has been used by the Australian government to evaluate university research performance.

I'm not sure what is the most stable link. But [this search seems to get a few copies of it](https://www.google.com.au/search?espv=2&q=era+journal+database+xls&oq=era+journal+database+xls&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.1410.3291.0.3509.10.9.1.0.0.1.238.992.0j3j2.5.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.serp..7.3.441.gxUSm-uWTbc).

It appears to have around 22 thousand journals. It contains ISSN and discipline category information.

See the list here:
http://www.arc.gov.au/era-2015-submitted-journal-list

Comment: This is no longer used.

Answer (score -1):

A place to start: [the ISSN Portal](https://portal.issn.org)
This will include not only journals, but magazines, newspapers, periodicals, and other continuing resources.